# Visually testing unusual code paths in ASP.NET WebForms Website

Tags: asp.net, testing, webforms

I have a large complex ASP.net WebForm website that I'm working on a visual redesign and am trying to think of good ways to exercise all the code paths in the website so I can see how things look with the redesign.

For example lets say I have a message that only gets displayed if there is an error which rarely happens. Here is an example of what my code might look like:

```
if (someErrorCondition) {
    someControl.Visible = true;
} else {
    someOtherControl.Visible = true;
}
```

This might not be a good way of doing things, but this is a good example of my existing code base I have to work with.

Let us assume for the sake of simplicity that I already have a way of testing one part of the `if`. The problem is exercising the other part without going through a lot of trouble to setup my environment to create an error.

One idea I had was to extract `someErrorCondition` into a method and in that method check for some session or request key to see if I want to fake a failure. Maybe wrap it in an `#if DEBUG` block so that it won't be compiled for production.

Any other ideas for how I might go about testing unusual code blocks on an ASP.net website so I can make sure nothing got left out in the redesign?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best solution is always the most simple. Since you obviously have access to the code, do a search for the Visible property for each form element within Visual Studio and set each one to true to see how it looks. Once you make the design change then un-comment the original code.

Example:

```
if (someErrorCondition) {
    someControl.Visible = true;
} else {
    someOtherControl.Visible = true;
}
```

TO

```
/* if (someErrorCondition) {
    someControl.Visible = true;
} else {
    someOtherControl.Visible = true;
}*/ someControl.Visible = true;
```

This is not good for testing proper behavior of the form, but will let you see how each element looks for visual design purposes.